# Remove zeros after decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If the number after decimals is 0 then remove the zero after decimal else display the number as it is.
Below is the example what I am trying to achieve in vue.

```
100.023 => 100.023
1230.0 => 1230
```

Comment: Watch the magic: `console.log(1230.0)` There are no significant digits in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
let s;

// example 1
s = (100.023).toPrecision();
console.log(s === '100.023');

// example 2
s = (1230.0).toPrecision();
console.log(s === '1230');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: unclear why one would need to use a method when there are not trailing zeros in JavaScript.....

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDecimal(num) {
    if (num % 1 !== 0) {
       return num;
}

return Math.trunc(num);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no significant digits in JavaScript so when you have the number 1234.0 it is 1234. If you have a string with "1243.0" convert it to a number and watch the decimal drop off.

```js
console.log(1234.0);
console.log(1234.056);
console.log(+"1234.0");
console.log(+"1234.056");
```

Answer (score -1):

---

### Also You Can Use the this##

```js
 UnitCost = 340.450000000;
 NewUnitCost =0;

NewUnitCost =FormatNum(UnitCost, 3);

OutPut:
NewUnitCost = 340.450
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems like this is not Javascript code